# How should NoSQL questions for specific engines be Tagged

Tags: discussion, tagging

I figure we would want to create the various nosql tags, (eg 'neo4j' from this question: [Amount of data per node in Neo4j](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4996/180))

This raised the question on how it should be tagged. Should they be tagged as both [nosql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nosql) 
and the specific engine tag?

I don't expect the SQL RDMS to be tagged as say, [oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) and [sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql), but there are fewer and more well known.

Comment: the reason I'm asking is, I can see wanting to get all questions on nosql, regardless of engine when researching the various nosql engine, then narrowing it down to specific engine tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will support this ***for now*** because it will generate better SEO and twitter responses, according to figures calculated by my fingers on a calculator at random. I also threw dice and chicken bones at a fire<sup>1</sup>, but I didn't get any results from those.

Additionally, when the site is popular enough that we can do without those tags, a dev can remove them from the database without causing a page-bump on all the old Qs

I would strongly caution against, however, going back and adding them en-masse to all the previously tagged questions. If you wanted you could re-tag them one at a time to add the new tag to the old sets.

Lastly, I would encourage the addition of this tag *only* when there would normally be four or less tags on a question. This should not supersede a more correct tag on a question (one of the reasons I *am* against this. That's just tag clutter).

---

<sup>1</sup> that's how voodoo economics works too, right?

Comment: I kept trying to upvote your comment about voodoo economics and failing. I got fooled by your footnote :(

Comment: There's something to be said for buzzword compliancy while we're trying to attract traffic to dba.se.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say yes, because:

1. At the moment there are very few [nosql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nosql) questions
2. I'm guessing many of the nosql products (eg [neo4j](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neo4j)) are not well known outside of those that use them

In the future if they become as large and well known as the major RDBMSs it may be unnecessary to use [nosql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nosql) as well.

I think the guiding principle should be whether adding the tag adds useful information for a significant number of users - adding [rdbms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdbms) to all [oracle](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle) questions clearly wouldn't

Comment: In the future ___when___ they become as large and well known <-- it's shake and bake and I hepped

Comment: I can't tell if you are joking or not. I assume you don't really practice voodoo?

Comment: I don't generally practice voodoo ;)